# Integrating ggplot() with manipulate() pickers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to combine ggplot and manipulate like this:

```
library(ggplot2);library(manipulate)

manipulate(
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = type, y = price)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 1/10) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm)
  type = picker("carat","depth","table")
)
```

*(where the manipulate function will change the x inputs with `picker`)*

But I am getting an `Error: unexpected ')' in ")"`

---

EDIT 1: fixed the syntax error (see: `({` ... `)},` )

```
manipulate({
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = type, y = price)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 1/10) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm)},
  type = picker("carat","depth","table")
)
```

Now I'm getting `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type manipulator.picker. Defaulting to continuous Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:type`

Comment: That's just a syntax error. You need to include a comma after the `geom_smooth(...)` and before `type=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the picker returns `"carat"` instead of `carat`, you should be using `aes_string`, rather than `aes`.

```
manipulate(
  ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x = type, y = "price")) +
    geom_point(alpha = 1/10) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm),
  type = picker("carat","depth","table")
)
```